# Flutter Provider best practice

Tags: flutter, provider

I have been experimenting with the provider package and am usually able to get it to do what I want it to do. However, in some cases I am not sure if what I am doing is at all best practice.

For example, suppose I have a settings page with various, unrelated options - say a theming option, a notifications option, some filter options specific to the app etc.

My question is, should each of these options have their own class dedicated to a single value so that only the parts of the widget tree dependent on that single value rebuild. Or should they all be in the same `SettingsProvider` class, and there is some way of using the fields in this class separately so as to avoid excessive rebuilds?

Or am I missing the bigger picture entirely? Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A solution I've found is to put all the values in a single class eg `SettingsProvider`. Then, instead of using `Provider.of<>` or `Consumer<>`,

use `Selector<>`. For example, to get/set the notifications option of settings, you could wrap the widget with a `Selector` like so -

```
Selector<SettingsProvider, bool>(
   builder: (context, notifications, child) {
      (notifications) 
      ? return Text('Notifications are on') 
      : return Text('Notifications are off')
   }, 
   selector: (context , settingsPro) => settingsPro.notifications,
),
```

This should display whether or not the notifications are on, and is only rebuilt when the notification option changes.

[Here is the provider doc page](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html)

[Here is an article about `Selector`](https://medium.com/@ggcsriram/flutter-provider-with-selector-4b469e6539a5)

Let me know if there are any better solutions.